# Qt Scrollbar in QLabel

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I have a small problem whit QScrollbar.

for example, 
This is a one my project in C#

[image]

At left panel, the user loads a graphic image and can pick elements.
but I see in Qt don't exist Split Panel whit automatic Scrollbar.
I tried to use QScrollArea, but if user maximizes Window it's a problem.

anyone have a solution or a good way to make this in qt?

Comment: When you used QScrollArea, did you used layout? on resize window layout will solve your problem.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html   ?

Comment: Actually, there is. You have to select 2 widgets and then in the toolbar, there is a button to create a splitter between them. It's right beneath the layout buttons and has two bars with an arrow in between as icon.

Comment: To add to @Felix, the class you are looking for is named [QSplitter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html)